# Как реализовать просмотр fixed блока?

Tags: css3, css, javascript

Здраствуйте!
Суть в следующем:

Есть меню `position: fixed`.
При уменьшении окна браузера появляется полоса прокрутки.
Но просмотреть полностью меню с помощью полосы прокрутки не получается, так оно ездит.

Подскажите, возможно ли реализовать так, чтобы меню можно было посмотреть полностью при использовании полосы прокрутки?

http://jsfiddle.net/gf94sd70/

1. Уменьшаем окно браузера.
2. Появляется полоса прокрутки.
3. Часть меню скрывается.
4. С помощью полосы прокрутки скрытую часть меню не удается посмотреть.

Comment: http://tsya.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` позиционируется относительно окна браузера. Из этого следует, что если ширина элемента больше ширины окна и элемент привязан к левому углу, то никак не увидишь обрезаемую часть. Можно сделать немного респонсива:

```
nav{
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
nav ul{
    max-width:450px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6n6obpzx/)

В этом случае у тебя менюха будет всегда влазить в экран. Либо можно воспользоваться JS для эмуляции `position: fixed` через `position: absolute`. Пример есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743123/fixed-positioning-in-mobile-safari)